# Twitter bootstrap popover : How to hide it on click outside, without using the body/document event handler?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using the bootstrap popover which is shown on the click of an  element.

Javascript :

```
var info = ui_utils.fa_button('icon-info', 'info', 'info', icon_style, false);
//please don't mind the custom function - it just adds the <i> element to the layout

$(info).popover({
    title: <some title>,
    html: true,
    content: <some content>,
    container: 'body',
    placement: 'right'
});

$(info).blur(function(){
   $(this).popover('hide');
});
```

The blur(or even focusout) event never gets triggered on clicking outside.

There must be a way to do this without using the document/body click event as it is suggested everywhere:

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function () {
        if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 &&         
           $(this).popover('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Anybody got a way out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        if(popovershow){
            popoverhide;
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if(popovershow){
            popoverhide;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about your answer.

Comment: I am looking for a way to do it without using any event on the body or document. Basically, something on the lines of focusout.